# Relational query fallback on translation model with Prisma

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, prisma

### Context

I am designing a schema that supports multi-language by following the 5-th design suggested by [this post](https://medium.com/kocsistem/what-is-the-best-database-design-for-multi-language-data-b21982dd7265) (the schema is shown below).
Now I am able to query a `Post` with a given `language` and `postId` by:

```js
await prisma.post.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: req.body.postId,
  },
  select: {
    translations: {
      where: {
        language: req.body.language
      }
    }
  }
});
```

### My Question

Unfortunately, the translations are not always available for all supported languages. I want to response with a fallback language when the user selected language is not presented in DB.

Besides:

1. performing a second query when the first query returns nothing,
2. always query the fallback language at the same time or
3. performing the query with raw sql magics

is there any way to make it using only one query?

### Schema

```
model Post {
  id           Int                @id
  translations PostTranslations[]
}

model PostTranslations {
  postId   Int
  language Language

  title   String
  content String

  post Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])

  @@id([language, postId])
}

enum Language {
  zh_TW
  en_US
  // ....
}
```

Comment: There are solutions but they would include use of raw query or performing a second query, I am not aware of any way through which you could achieve this in a single query without always fetching the fallback language translation.

Comment: @NurulSundarani Thank you for your comment!
I've realized that this requires acknowledgment of the data existence before sending the query, otherwise, some raw SQL magic is needed.
I will adopt one of the above solutions depending on the use case as a workaround. Thank you for your confirmation!